# Python Kivy is not working on windows

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I have just downloaded kivy.

```
python -m pip install Kivy
```

I found a simple example and it is not working. The error is `Unable to find any valuable Window provider.` I already tried to install `pyglet` `pygame` `glfw` `pyopengl` `cython`. I also downloaded the `sdl2.dll` and placed next to the python file.

Code

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Stack trace

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Administrator\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-06-15_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
File "d:\...\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "d:\...\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\...\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
    retval = self.func(inst)
File "d:\...\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
    EventLoop.ensure_window()
File "d:\...\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kivy** dependencies must be installed explicitly:

```
pip install kivy kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
```

An example code:

```
import struct

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Callback
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import ModernGL


class CustomWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:

            self.ctx = ModernGL.create_context()

            self.vert = self.ctx.vertex_shader('''
                #version 330

                in vec2 vert;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0.0, 1.0);
                }
            ''')

            self.frag = self.ctx.fragment_shader('''
                #version 330

                out vec4 color;

                void main() {
                    color = vec4(0.30, 0.50, 1.00, 1.0);
                }
            ''')

            self.prog = self.ctx.program([self.vert, self.frag])

            self.vbo = self.ctx.buffer(struct.pack('6f', 0.0, 0.8, -0.6, -0.8, 0.6, -0.8))
            self.vao = self.ctx.simple_vertex_array(self.prog, self.vbo, ['vert'])

            self.draw()

            Callback(self.draw)

    def draw(self, *args):
        self.ctx.clear(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.vao.render()

    def ask_update(self, *largs):
        self.canvas.ask_update()


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = root = CustomWidget()
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```